# Relative path import fails, module not found, but absolute path import works

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've had this issue for a while now and tried to find fixes for it.
I'm developing my discord.js bot and recently migrated from TS back to JS because of certain problems i've experienced with it. Upon migrating, however, I was met with an issue of Node.js not finding my command handler file using relative paths. VSCode resolves the path and suggests me the file, reading the directory with `fs.readdir('./commands')` also showed the handler file. So far I've tried:

1. Switching to dynamic import (`await import('...')`) -> didn't work
2. Removing the first part of the import (`const { ... } =` ) -> works
3. Commenting the handler import line off, so Node.js would import the next file -> didn't work, no imports are successful
4. Using full path to the handler file (`await import('file://C:/.../emberbot/commands/handler.js')`)

Directory tree:

```
emberbot
├── commands
│   ├── config.js
│   ├── convert.js
│   ├── dn.js
│   ├── eval.js
│   ├── exit.js
│   ├── handler.js
│   ├── hi.js
│   ├── info.js
│   ├── minecraft.js
│   ├── pfp.js
│   ├── ping.js
│   ├── poll.js
│   ├── quote.js
│   ├── rcg.js
│   ├── rng.js
│   ├── suggest.js
│   └── talkingben.js
├── config.json
├── index.js
├── misc.json
├── modules
│   ├── ben.js
│   ├── bots-moe.js
│   ├── chatbot.js
│   ├── client.js
│   ├── config.js
│   ├── interfaces.d.ts
│   ├── logger.js
│   └── misc.js
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

(not full, cleared up of certain garbage that don't relate at all)

**Full source code: https://github.com/NoNameLmao/emberbot (up to date with this question)**

Comment: `fs.readdir()` uses the current working directory to resolve relative paths.  `import` uses the module directory containing the code.  If the module directory isn't what you want for `import`, build an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Since relative paths are processed to the current working directory of your app, and the current working directory being a variable depending on where you start your application, its always advisable to resolve imports to the root file. This is why the absolute import works but the others fail.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73339464) for some context

you can use [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname)

Your code becomes

```
fs.readdir(__dirname + '/commands')
```

So you code will read